# C# file comparison utility

Tags: c#, file-comparison

Can you recommend a good file comparison utility that is able to handle C# very well. I have tried both WinMerge, BeyondCompare and KDiff and they are not good enough, e.g. if I have functions with the same name but placed in different areas of the file they show it as differences.

Comment: Please, see my new answer, and, if you think that it's the correct one, mark it. The only reason is to make it useful for the community. Five years ago the situation was quite different.

Comment: I agree with @JotaBe, the situation has changed and his answer is now more accurate. I have updated my answer to direct to his, but if you still use this account you should update the accepted answer to his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Update (2015)**: Since writing this answer there are now more modern tools that can do structural and semantic merging and diffing of code in various languages. See [JotaBe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819534/119738) for some examples]

**Original answer (2010)**:
Unfortunately, that is kind of the nature of Diff. It's always been a line by line comparison, it's not a language aware comparison. As far as I am aware there is nothing that does what you are asking for (It's always possible I'm wrong though).

You could use a tool like [regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) to standardize class layout before you do the comparison. This would order all your methods, so you wouldn't have the problem with a method of the same name being in different places in a file.

Comment: The regionerate alternative is brilliant, but there are now powerful tools that can perfectly do what the question asks, without needing to modify your code at all. An they can even do more interesting things. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment (april 2015), there are at least 3 commercial comparison tools that have into account the structure of C# code files to make an advanced diff and merge between code files:

- [Coode Software](http://www.coodesoft.com/) Code Compare++
- [Devart Code Compare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/)
- [Semantic Merge](https://www.semanticmerge.com/)

These three tools support this kind of advanced comparison only on the payed versions (or the trial periods). AFAIK there is no free tool that can do this.

Comment: I pay for SemanticMerge and it's well worth the $3/month.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I am aware of that may be able to do this (I am not sure it can) is [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

As far as I know, it can track functions even if they are moved to different files, so using it in this scenario would not show a difference.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897585/how-does-git-handle-merging-code-that-was-moved-to-a-different-file/1915646#1915646) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Devart CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) for this task. Native VS editor allows me to  handle C# and VB very well. They call this feature "Structure comparison". It will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find a text compare utility that will do this.  You're better off reorganizing the functions so they are in the same places.  I've seen designer generated code do this (ie, move functions around every time the file gets regenerated).  Its annoying, but I don't think you're going to get around it.  BeyondCompare really is one of the best comparison utilities out there.