# git merge: apply changes to code that moved to a different file

Tags: git

I am attempting a pretty beefy git merge maneuver right now.  One problem that I am coming across is that I made some changes to some code in my branch, but my colleague moved that code to a new file in his branch.  So when I did `git merge my_branch his_branch`, git did not notice that the code in the new file was the same as the old, and so none of my changes are there.

What's the easiest way to go about applying my changes again to the code in the new files.  I won't have too many problems finding out which commits need to be reapplied (I can just use `git log --stat`).  But as far as I can tell, there is no way to get git to reapply the changes into the new files.  The easiest thing I am seeing right now is to manually reapply the changes, which is not looking like a good idea.

I know that git recognizes blobs, not files, so surely there must be a way to tell it, "apply this exact code change from this commit, except not where it was but where it now is in this new file".

Comment: Not exactly the same, but here is a similar question with good anwsers that might apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701790/git-merge-with-renamed-files

Comment: None of the answers describe _why_ git isn't able to perform merges like this automatically. I thought it was supposed to be smart enough to detect renames and perform the appropriate merge automatically?

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't true when the question was asked, but modern versions of git (I'm using 1.9.5) can merge changes across renamed and moved files. There is even a `--rename-threshold` option to tweak the amount of similarity that is required.

Comment: @ToddOwen that will work if you are doing a vanilla rebase off of an upstream branch, but you'll still run into trouble if you're cherry picking or back-porting a range of changes that may not include the commit that renames the files.

Comment: Is/was this a problem at all if you do a rebase first?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and I resolved it by rebasing my work to match the target file organization. This works because git keep tracks of files *content*, so by rebasing on top of a rename, the changes are applied as necessary.

More precisely, let's say that you modified `original.txt` on your branch (the `local` branch), but on the master branch, `original.txt` has been copied to another one, say `copy.txt`.
This copy has been done in a commit that we name commit `CP`.

You want to apply all your local changes, commits `A` and `B` below, that were made on `original.txt`, to the new file `copy.txt`.

```
 ---- X -----CP------ (master)
       \ 
        `--A---B--- (local)
```

Create a throwaway branch `move` at the starting point of your changes with `git branch move X`. That is to say, put the `move` branch at commit `X`, the one before the commits you want to merge; most likely, this is the commit from which you branched out to implement your changes. As user *@digory doo* wrote below, you can do `git merge-base master local` to find `X`.

```
 ---- X (move)-----CP----- (master)
       \ 
        `--A---B--- (local)
```

On this branch, issue the following renaming command:

```
git mv original.txt copy.txt
```

This renames the file. Note that `copy.txt` did not yet exist in your tree at this point.
Commit your change (we name this commit `MV`).

```
        ,--MV (move)
       /
 ---- X -----CP----- (master)
       \ 
        `--A---B--- (local)
```

You can now rebase your work on top of `move`:

```
git rebase move local
```

This should work without problem, and your changes are applied to `copy.txt` in your local branch.

```
        ,--MV (move)---A'---B'--- (local)
       /
 ---- X -----CP----- (master)
```

Now, you do not necessarily want or need to have commit `MV` in your main branch's history, because the move operation may lead to a conflict with the copy operation at commit `CP` in the main branch.

You only have to rebase your work again, discarding the move operation, as follows:

```
git rebase move local --onto CP
```

... where `CP` is the commit where `copy.txt` was introduced in the other branch.
This rebases all the changes on `copy.txt` on top of the `CP` commit.
Now, your `local` branch is exactly as if you always modified `copy.txt` and not `original.txt`, and you can continue merging with others.

```
                ,--A''---B''-- (local)
               /
 -----X-------CP----- (master)
```

It is important that the changes are applied on `CP` or otherwise `copy.txt` would not exist and the changes would be applied back on `original.txt`.

Hope this is clear.
This answer comes late, but this may be useful to someone else.

Comment: That's a lot of work, but I think it should work in principle. I think you'll have better luck with merge than rebase, though.

Comment: This solution only involves basic git commands, unlike editing patches or using `patch` (which involves also potentially a lot of work), and that's why I thought it could be interesting to show it. Also, note that I took more time to write the answer than to actually apply the changes, in my case. At which step would you recommand using a merge? and why? The only difference I see is that by rebasing, I make a temporary commit that is later discarded (commit `MV`), which is not possible with merges only.

Comment: With rebase, you have a higher chance of dealing with merge conflicts, because you deal with each commit, whereas with a merge you deal with everything at once, meaning some changes that might have happened with a rebase would be nonexistent with a merge. What I would do is merge, then manually move the merged file. Maybe I misunderstood the idea of your answer, though.

Comment: I added some ASCII trees to clarify the approach. Regaring merge vs. rebase in that case: what I want to do is take all the changes on 'original.txt' in my branch and apply them to 'copy.txt' in the master branch, because for some reason, 'original.txt' was copied (and not moved) into 'copy.txt' at some point. After that copy, 'original.txt' may also have evolved on the master branch. If I merged directly, my local changes on original.txt would be applied to the modified original.txt in master branch, which would be difficult to merge. Regards.

Comment: I see. I would recommend just doing `git merge local` from `move`, then manually copying over the file to your original `local` branch.  This has git doing less of the work for you (you are manually copying the file), but it will end up being easier because merge conflicts are simpler when merging than when rebasing.

Comment: I see how you could merge `local` from `move`, indeed, and then move the file. In practice this depends on context and taste. I would just highlight that those particular rebase operations are unlikely to introduce conflicts by themselves (there can be conflict between `local` and `master` afterwards, but that is another matter). Thanks for accepting this answer :-)

Comment: The issue is that you can have a branch that merges cleanly, but rebases with conflicts, because later commits "remove" the conflicts.  Anyway, if literally moving the file feels too "un-git-ish" to you, you could always use git to do it: `git checkout move -- file`.

Comment: I understand why conflict resolution with merge can be prefered over rebase, for the reason you gave. But there is definitely a case for rebase operations and this one seems appropriate. Conflict may arise when rebasing `local` from `X` to `CP`, and unfortunately, if this is the case, it depends on the actual context; then, you may decide it is more effective to copy the resulting file, or whatever works, than to resolve each conflict in the rebase. I won't argue because this might be the good choice in practice.

Comment: Will this work if `copy.txt` actually existed beforehand and it was replaced by the `CP` commit?

Comment: @texasflood Yes, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @coredump In this scenario I get a conflict when rebasing with `git rebase move local`.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @coredump I kind of figured it out.  If your original.txt is blank, then you get the merge conflict when rebasing, but if your original.txt has content then it works.

Comment: This failed for me where `copy.txt` already existed - not that I'm sure that is why it failed.

Comment: @PaulGardiner It's hard to understand why, maybe you would have better luck by writing a separate question

Answer (score 37):

You can always use `git diff` (or `git format-patch`) to generate the patch, then go manually edit the filenames in the patch, and apply it with `git apply` (or `git am`).

Short of this, the only way it's going to work automatically is if git's rename detection can figure out that the old and new files are the same thing - which it sounds like they aren't really in your case, just a chunk of them. It's true that git uses blobs, not files, but a blob is just the contents of an entire file, without the filename and metadata attached. So if you have a chunk of code moved between two files, they aren't really the same blob - the rest of the blob's content is different, just the chunk in common.

Comment: Well, it's the best answer so far.   I couldn't figure out how to make `git format-patch` work for a commit.  If I do `git format-patch SHA1`, it generates a whole bunch of patch files for the whole history.  

But I guess `git show SHA1 > diff.patch` will work just as well.

Comment: @asmeurer: use the `-1` option. The normal mode of operation for format-patch is a revision range, like `origin/master..master`, so you can easily prepare a patch series.

Comment: Actually, another note.  `git apply` and `git am` are too picky, because they want the same line numbers.  But I am currently being successful with the UNIX `patch` command.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a **merge** solution of encountering a merge conflict with rename and edit and resolving it with mergetool recognizing the correct 3 merge source files.

- After a merge fails because of 'deleted file' that you realize was renamed and edited:

1. You abort the merge.
2. Commit renamed files on your branch.
3. And merge again.

Walk-through:

Create a file.txt:

```bash
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git-rename-and-modify-test/.git/

$ echo "A file." > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -am "file.txt added."
 [master (root-commit) 401b10d] file.txt added.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
```

Create a branch where you will edit later:

```bash
$ git branch branch-with-edits
 Branch branch-with-edits set up to track local branch master.
```

Create the rename and edit on master:

```bash
$ git mv file.txt renamed-and-edited.txt
$ echo "edits on master" >> renamed-and-edited.txt 
$ git commit -am "file.txt + edits -> renamed-and-edited.txt."
 [master def790f] file.txt + edits -> renamed-and-edited.txt.
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 file.txt
 create mode 100644 renamed-and-edited.txt
```

Swap to branch, and edit there too:

```bash
$ git checkout branch-with-edits 
 Switched to branch 'branch-with-edits'
 Your branch is behind 'master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
$ 
$ echo "edits on branch" >> file.txt 
$ git commit -am "file.txt edited on branch."
 [branch-with-edits 2c4760e] file.txt edited on branch.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Attempt to merge master:

```bash
$ git merge master
 CONFLICT (modify/delete): file.txt deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of file.txt left in tree.
 Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Notice the conflict is hard to resolve - and that files were renamed. Abort, mimic the rename:

```bash
$ git merge --abort
$ git mv file.txt renamed-and-edited.txt
$ git commit -am "Preparing for merge; Human noticed renames files were edited."
 [branch-with-edits ca506da] Preparing for merge; Human noticed renames files were edited.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
rename file.txt => renamed-and-edited.txt (100%)
```

Try merge again:

```bash
$ git merge master
 Auto-merging renamed-and-edited.txt
 CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in renamed-and-edited.txt
 Recorded preimage for 'renamed-and-edited.txt'
 Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Great! Merge results in a 'normal' conflict that can be resolved with mergetool:

```bash
$ git mergetool
 Merging:
 renamed-and-edited.txt

 Normal merge conflict for 'renamed-and-edited.txt':
 {local}: created file
 {remote}: created file
$ git commit 
 Recorded resolution for 'renamed-and-edited.txt'.
 [branch-with-edits 2264483] Merge branch 'master' into branch-with-edits
```

Comment: In that solution, it seems to me that the first step, the merge that is aborted, is only useful to find out which files were renamed and edited remotely. If you know them in advance. You could skip that step and, basically, the solution is simply to rename the files manually locally and then merge and resolve the conflicts as usual.

Comment: Thank you. My situation was that I moved `B.txt -> C.txt` and `A.txt -> B.txt` with git mv, and git couldn't automatically match the merge conflicts correctly (was getting merge conflicts between old `B.txt` and new `B.txt`). By using this method, the merge conflicts are now between the correct files.

Comment: This only works when the whole file is moved, but git should generally detect that situation automatically. The tricky situation is when only part of a file is moved.

Answer (score 3):

My quick solution to this problem (in my case it was not a single file, but a whole directory structure) was:

- move the file(s) in "my_branch" to the location where they are in "his_branch" (git rm / git add)
- `git commit -m "moved to original location for merging"`
- `git merge his_branch` (no conflicts this time!)
- move the file(s) to my desired location (git rm / git add)
- `git commit -m "moved back to final location after merge"`

You will have two additional commits in the history.

But since git tracks the moving of the files, `git blame`, `git log` etc will still work on these files, since the commits that moved the files did not change them. So I don't see any drawback to this method and it's very straightforward to understand.