# git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo

Tags: git

I have a `repo1` and `repo2` on local machine. They are very similar, but the latter is some kind of other branch (`repo1` is not maintained anymore).

```
/path/to/repo1 $ git log HEAD~5..HEAD~4
<some_sha> Add: Introduce feature X
```

How to apply changes made by commit `<some_sha>` in `repo1` to `repo2`?

Do I need to prepare some patch, or is it possible to do some `cherry-pick` between the repos?

How about doing the same but for range of commits?

Comment: Can't you just pull from repo1 to repo2?

Comment: for the slightly more specific case where you're looking to apply changes to a file or files that were moved in one of the repositories, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491270/git-merge-apply-changes-to-code-that-moved-to-a-different-file

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As a hack, you can try modifying [recipe for comparing commits in two different repositories on GitTips page](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_compare_two_local_repositories), i.e.:

```
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=../repo/.git/objects \
git cherry-pick $(git --git-dir=../repo/.git rev-parse --verify <commit>)
```

where `../repo` is path to the other repository.

With modern Git you can use multiple revisions and revision ranges with [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html).

The `$(git --git-dir=../repo/.git rev-parse --verify <commit>)`
is here to translate `<commit>` (for example `HEAD`, or `v0.2`, or `master~2`, which are values in the second repository you copy from) into SHA-1 identifier of commit.  If you know SHA-1 of a change you want to pick, it is not necessary.

**NOTE** however that Git can skip copying objects from source repository, as it doesn't know that the alternate object repository is only temporary, for one operation. You might need to copy objects from the second repository with:

```
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=../repo/.git/objects git repack -a -d -f
```

This puts those objects borrowed from second repository in original repository storage

*Not tested.*

---

A not so hacky solution is to follow [knittl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816292/46058):

- Go to second repository you want to copy commits from, and generate patches from commits you want with `git format-patch`
- Optionally, copy patches (0001-* etc.) to your repository
- Use `git am --3way` to apply patches

Comment: Works good. If you have problems with commit then do 'git reset HEAD; git add .'.

Comment: this is awesome -- how would you do a range of commits?  just sha1...sha2?

Comment: I also get `fatal: unable to read tree ...` but after `git reset HEAD^` everything works fine

Comment: @hvgotcodes it worked for me simply by passing the range as `<commit>` but the `rev-parse --verify` command doesn't like it as it accepts only single commit values.
But as `cherry-pick` accepts both single and range commit values, I ask: why is `rev-parse` needed?

Comment: @Chuim: `git rev-parse` is needed if you want to refer to a commit by its ref-based name in other repository, e.g. `master`, `HEAD^^`, or something like that; rev-parse turns it into universal SHA-1 identifier.

Comment: Thanks @JakubNarębski. It seemed to work as the commits were applied and showed up in the log. But somehow the repository would get corrupted (missing blobs) and I got the same `fatal: unable to read <SHA1>` described above. In my case `git reset HEAD` didn't help.

Comment: @Chuim : One thing that could happen (but shouldn't) is that Git performs operation assuming that objects in temporary alternate are always available. You can try (after cherry-pick) `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=../repo/.git/objects git repack -a -d -f` to put those objects in original repository storage, then `git gc`. HTH.

Comment: Thanks again @JakubNarębski. I finally when the route of the `format-patch | am` answer which proved simpler, safer and directly accepts both single commits and ranges.

Comment: Can a `.diff` be taken of the `repo1` and applied to the `repo 2` by way of `git apply`?

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol : Yes, `git am` uses `git apply` to apply the patch; however `git apply` would not create a commit, only apply changes, it is also limited in its ability to resolve conflicts (when patch no longer applies cleanly because file is different).

Answer (score 255):

You can to use [`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) in your first repository and then [`git am`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) to apply that patch in your second repository:

```
/path/to/1 $ git format-patch sha1^..sha1
/path/to/1 $ cd /path/to/2
/path/to/2 $ git am -3 /path/to/1/0001-…-….patch
```

Or, in one line:

```
/path/to/2 $ git --git-dir=/path/to/1/.git format-patch --stdout sha1^..sha1 | git am -3
```

Comment: This solution proved simpler and safer than the accepted answer of direct cherry-picking using `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` (that one would corrupt my repository).

Comment: When there are conflicts it won't work because it fails to find the commits on the other branch.

Comment: Adding `--ignore-whitespace` to the `git am` command may resolve any conflicts and avoid needing to perform a 3-way merge

Comment: If you just want the latest commit: `git format-patch HEAD^1`

Comment: Note that this patch will be applied to the current branch in `/path/to/2`, so if you want to switch to the branch you made the commits on in the other repo, do that before running `git am -3 ...`.

Answer (score 119):

You can do [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) if you add the second repo as a remote to the first (and then `fetch`).

Comment: That's actually the proper way to do it.

Comment: This feels like the right way to me as well. And I just used it and it worked well for me.

Comment: I would rather say: do `git fetch [remote-name]` in the second repo and then `git cherry-pick [sha1]`.

Comment: This approach worked great for me, thanks.  Since the second repo was also local, just had to use a file URI when adding it as a remote.

Comment: Sounds like this really should be the best answer

Comment: In my case, I have two clones of a gigantic remote git repository (to allow parallel work), meaning all of its history is already downloaded and stored twice in my HD. If I should also have to add each as a remote of the other, that would create yet two extra copies of the same history and would potentially require syncs among them before I would be able to `cherry-pick`.
So even though it might feel like the "right" way, it is not always the most practical.

Comment: This really should be the best answer, just tried and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm having a hard time when to know to use cherry-pick vs rebase.  I rebased already, but not all the commits came with that rebase.  It only rebased up to some common time.  Now I am trying to move the, possibly, newer commits over.  I think this answer sums that up.

Comment: Ok, that was my bad, I later realized that the commits weren't there because i was comparing my local copy of the remote repo, but fetching from remote copy, i needed to `git push` those commits up to the remote repo first, then fetch again. `rebase -i` is still the way to go for me.

Comment: If anybody wondering how to add a local repo as a remote to another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603750/9157799

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small script for applying the diff output of repo diff
https://github.com/raghakh/android-dev-scripts/commit/a57dcba727d271bf2116f981392b0dcbb22734d0

Comment: How do get the diff output to feed to your script?