# Referencing the sha1 in one local repo from within another local repo in git

Tags: git, repository, fetch, sha1

I have two git repos that I cloned on my local machine.  I'm attempting to apply a change from one repo to the other:

```
cd path/to/local-repo1
git fetch path/to/local-repo2 <sha1>
// cherry-pick from fetch head, etc.
```

I'm getting:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref <sha1>
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I found [git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816040/git-apply-changes-introduced-by-commit-in-one-repo-to-another-repo), but why is it that git does not recognize the sha1 in another local repo?  Turns out that if I replace the sha1 with the name of a branch, it succeeds, but I need to do this with a multitude of sha1's and don't really want to create a branch on each one in order to reference them.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your specific question, but you don't *have* to create branches and fetch each one. You could just add `local-repo2` as a remote and `git fetch local-repo2`, then cherry-pick the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

The form of `git fetch` that you're trying to use is:

```
git fetch <repository> <refspec>
```

However, your SHA1sum is (unlikely to be!) a valid refspec.  A refspec defines a mapping between refs (usually branch names) between the source and destination repository.  SHA1sums (object names) are distinct from refs, and the error is telling you that when you do `git fetch path/to/local-repo2 f414f31`, it's expanding the refspec to `f414f31:f414f31` and then failing to find the ref `f414f31` in the remote repository.  That's because it's not a ref.

So, assuming that your commit is on local branch in the remote repository, I would do the following:

```
git remote add other-local path/to/local-repo2
git fetch other-local
git cherry-pick f414f31
```

The form `git fetch <remote-name>` fetches all the local branches in the remote repository to remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/<remote-name>`, and makes sure that all the objects necessary for those branches (including all the commits in the history) are present in your local repository.