# Copying a git repository to USB drive

Tags: git

I am working on an Open Source project and I have a git repo on my machine with all the code. The repo is kind of big, and I would like to keep working on it while I do not have access to my computer.

If I copy the repo into my USB drive will it still be behaving as if I was on the original repo in my machine (same configurations, etc.)?

If copying does not work, is there a way of achieving this without having to recreate the repo from scratch on the USB drive?

Comment: Yes it would work just fine. Keep in mind though that certain behaviours may be different because of the (possibly) different configurations in your global git configuration file.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: the USB drive, if formatted as FAT, may be unable to represent certain content in the git repo like file permissions, case-sensitive naming (especially files with same name up to case like `README` and `Readme`), symlinks, etc.

Comment: yes, it would work the same as long as your copy doesn't omit the `.git` folder inside the repo. So be sure to copy the root directory, not all files inside it. Regarding git behaviour, make sure you configure eveyrhing _locally_ (use the `--local` [flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) )

Comment: @R.. The permissions thing is important

Comment: I've seen so many broken git repos where every file is +x from broken FAT/Windows setups...

Comment: @R A good technique for preserving permissions of the contents of a folder (and generally most metadata you might care about) that I use often is `tar cvpzf` - reliable, fast, and easy to remember.

Comment: the repo on your machine is the only copy of the repo and there is no other accessible from elsewhere?

Answer (score 39):

It will work, but certain config variables won't travel with you.

Git has three levels of configuration: system-wide (all users on a PC), global (user-specific) and repo-specific.

The repo-specific configs will move around with your repo; the system and global configs won't. I would check your config files and if necessary also grab a copy of your user-specific configs.

Comment: A big one on this front is your author info (name and e-mail). Those are often stored in global config, since you frequently use the same one for all repos.

Comment: @jpmc26 To add to that, they **can** be moved to the repo level, see http://dereenigne.org/git/set-git-email-address-on-a-per-repository-basis

Comment: @AMomchilov Don't you then have to add the repo config to your .gitignore? I imagine at least some projects check in a repo-level config to control settings like core.autocrlf.

Comment: @Doval: Nope, what makes you think that?

Comment: Copying a repo is bad practice, it is far better to do what @microbial suggests. That is treat the repository on the USB as a secondary `bare` repository that you can push and pull from. You then setup your credentials on both machines separately. No one here was pointing this out. I would have down voted the question but do not have enough rep at this time.

Answer (score 35):

The best way is to add a remote (even though it's a local folder).  In this way you can always transfer commits between the two.  When you want to move

```
git init /mnt/usb/repo
git remote add usb /mnt/usb/repo
git push usb master
```

The last command can be used to push any branches into the folder as desired.  If the local branch has no remote currently set as upstream you may have to do `--set-upstream`.

See also
[git how to add a local repo and treat it as a remote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/git-how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-one) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: May you elaborate on why?

Comment: I foresee forgetting to push to the USB repo before leaving one day.

Comment: Better make it bare repo: `git init --bare` - only the git meta data is transferred, no actual files in the work tree. This assumes that you have every change you care about committed to the repository (maybe in a throw-away work-in-progress branch). Bare repositories will have much less hassle with the file types, modes and permissions or even file names that FATFS cannot reproduce. Could also pack the repo before copying to USB storage to save space and perhaps make the operation faster.

Comment: Creating a 'remote' on the USB is the essence of git - distributed version control - isn't it? Changes made to the 'remote' on the USB and on 'my machine' can happen independently; especially if he forgets to push to the USB repo before leaving one day. He can pull, cherry pick, stash - whatever steps are necessary get things back in sync. I do this all the time when syncing up copies of repos when a network connection is not available.

Comment: There's also the matter of the stashes.

Comment: This won't copy repo configuration in `.git/config` (filemode, autocrlf, git-svn, etc). Diffing that file in both repos can help ensure your usb remote matches your main checkout.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda don't like the idea of copying git repositories from one place to another. Instead, I absolutely would recommend using a remote server for your code.

There's at least 2 excellent git as service around: the most famous is [GitHub](https://github.com), which will freely host your code if you don't mind sharing it in a public repository. If you want to keep it private and don't want to pay for it, go for [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org).

Comment: As I have said, I am working for an Open Source project, so remote repositories are all taken care of. What I wanted was to take my configurations with me (branches, identification, aliases, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same situation as you. After some digging, I cloned the repo onto my usb drive, then cloned the repo from the usb to the other computer; and then changed the remote for the repo on the new computer using: git remote set-url origin

You can make sure the origin you added is correct using:

1. git remote -v, or,
2. git log, to make sure you can see the commits made on the original repo