# How to create a local push destination on a hard disk using Git

Tags: git

I want to make a local push destination on my hard disk on *Git*, and use that destination(folder) for *push* and *pull* instead of adding an remote repository.
How do I do that in *Git*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/git-how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-one

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the folder you want to have your **remote** in

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/my-remote
   ```
2. Create a bare repository there via [git init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)

   ```
   $ git init --bare
   ```
3. Go to the repository you want to work in and add a new remote pointing to the previously created repository via [git remote add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

   ```
   $ git remote add <name-of-remote> /path/to/my-remote
   ```
4. After these steps you should be able to push to your new remote `<name-of-remote>`

   ```
   $ git push -u <name-of-remote> master
   ```

   Where `-u` is used to set the upstream of your branch, only needed the first time you push.

Comment: @AnimiVulpins Thank you!

Comment: For an initial local remote and initial starting repo of source code, the --bare was the only thing that worked for me.  Just doing git init ./ gave me errors when I did git push.

Comment: @JimSan It would be really helpful to know what errors you got and what you mean by: "Initial starting repo of source code" (a repository with no commits yet?)

Comment: Without the --bare I get half a page of error when trying to push to it: "remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
 error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
 is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
 with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
 the work tree to HEAD.
 
 You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
 to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into

Comment: remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
 arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
 other way.
 
 To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/carlo/projects/aicxx/ai-evio-testsuite/tmp/my_remote2
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)"

Comment: @CarloWood Thanks for your update on my answer. For empty local remotes a `--bare` repository is many times easier as it does not force you to set any unusual configs.