# Local repos as dependencies

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-link

I am developing in two repos, one a dependency of the other. I am on npm v5. I specify the dependency in `package.json` of `main-repo` as `../dependent-repo`. When I do `npm install`, this creates a symlink for `dependent-repo` in `main-repo/node_modules`, pointing to `../../dependent-repo`.

The problem is that `dependent-repo` has its own `node_modules` underneath it, so when I refer to (require or import) something in one of **its** dependencies, the default resolution procedure resolves to the dependency in `dependent-repo/node_modules`, rather than the dependency in `main-repo/node_modules`.

This turns out to be a problem with TypeScript, since apparently it believes that `main-repo/node_modules/@angular/core` is distinct from `dependent-repo/node_modules/@angular/core`, even if they are the same version, and byte-for-byte identical. This gives rise to TS errors of the form

> Argument of type 'ViewContainerRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewContainerRef'.

I am familiar with this problem because it also occurred with npm v3 when I used `npm link`. That problem has been discussed extensively on the TS issues list, but with no resolution as far as I can tell. I was hoping that npm v5 would somehow magically solve this issue, but no luck so far.

I tried specifying the dependency as `file://../dependent-repo`, but this also merely creates the same symlink (as least in npm5; I seem to recall that in earlier versions if may have copied the directory lock, stock and barrel).

At the moment the only workaround I can see is leaving the dependency to point to the github server, then committing and pushing every single change I make, and re-running `npm install` on the main repo to bring in the latest changes. This was exactly what I was trying to avoid.

I thought of temporarily renaming `dependent-repo/node_modules` before testing `main-repo`, so it is omitted from the resolution process. However, this obviously requires all dependencies of `dependent-repo` to be present on `main-repo`.

I tried playing a bit with the `paths` option to `tsconfig.json` (in `main-repo`), and had some luck with things like `paths: {"*": ["node_modules"]}`, but couldn't get this to work completely.

I understand that `angular-cli` may have made some changes to its internal webpack configuration to make this work better, but unfortunately my `main-repo` uses an older webpack build process, and I could not make some of the suggested changes such as `resolve: {fallback: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]}` or `resolve: { modules: [ path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") ] }` work for me.

Comment: I know you were trying to avoid the Git-based dependency style, but it is the safest way to handle NodeJS sub dependencies, specially if your project grows and uses stuff as containers and CI. I would start by doing some automation using git-hooks and NPM scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new remote to git in the `dependent` repo, but the new "remote" will be somewhere on your local box. This way, you can do `git push <remote-name> <branch>` and point the repo url in your `main` repo to pull from your remote.
[[git how to add a local repo and treat it as a remote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/git-how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-one])
it's a hacky solution but should alleviate some pain when used with a couple of makefiles.

Comment: makefiles? What are those?