# How to push existing local repo to remote

Tags: git

I am new to GIT.

I have used `git init` to create a new GIT repo locally. I have practiced with add/commit. Now I want to try using git pull/push and for this I need a remote repository.

I can create a repo on github and clone it on my local machine. Instead, I want to use the existing local repo from my PC and push it somewhere. I guess to github? What is the way to do this?

Comment: If you just want to experiment, you could just clone your repo locally.
`git clone path/to/original/repo`.
Now you can go to the newly cloned repo and experiment with pulling/pushing to your original repo.

Comment: No. I have a repo on my PC. I want to put this on remote.

Comment: GitHub will have readily available documentation on how to do this. It should be available on a newly created repo, without even having to go looking for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `git remote` to do this.

Just add a remote repo to your local repo with:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/yourRepository.git
```

Then you can do your first push. With simple command `git push`.

After that you can do all remote operation like **fetch,pull and push**.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to train your push/pull skills you can definitely create a GitHub project and then use that.

The way to do it is to go to your GH account, go to `new repository`, then when you create it you'll have this screen infront of you.

[image]

You can see that there is a section for `...or push an existing repository from the command line`. Execute the two commands you see there in your local repository and then you'll be ready to go!

But wait, there is more. You don't even have to use GitHub to have a remote! [You can have your very own remote locally!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-repo)

You can create a local directory, let's call it `local-git-repo.git`

```sh
mkdir local-git-repo.git
```

Then in it we can execute

```sh
git init --bare
```

Then in your actual projcet you can do the following

```sh
git add remote origin <path to your git repo>
```

and done! You have your own local repo which you can maintain!

Comment: This is a duplicate questions, and I would like to delete it. For this, please can you delete your answer.

Comment: @variable Why do you want to delete the question instead of leaving it up for others?  It might help other people.  This question, and its answers, are not *just for you*, they are for everyone who might have the same situation.