# Apply all commits from one repo to another

Tags: git, svn, github, migration, git-svn

Context: My job decided to switch from subversion to git. They have 5 svn repos that need to be converted, 4 of which are small and can be migrated with git-svn in under an hour. The last is much bigger and git-svn runs for days and eventually crashes, so i've been experimenting with other tools like subgit, svn2git, KDE's svn2git, etc. All of them fail at the same point, a revision over a year ago, and crash.

KDE's svn2git has been the fastest and most effective so far, and its rules have allowed me to create two git repos: one with all the commits before the problem, and one with all the commits after. Now i need to correctly merge them into one git repo.

I know how to add one repo as a remote of another and cherry pick the commits over ([git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816040/git-apply-changes-introduced-by-commit-in-one-repo-to-another-repo)), but I need a way to do it over the entire repo and all its branches.

How can i apply all of the commits of one repo on top of another?

Edit: I'm looking to do something similar to what git rebase does so that the history is complete and accurate across the entire repository

Comment: Maybe something you can do with `git filter-branch`?  You could also look at `git replace` which would be super fast.  How big the SVN repository in terms of commits?

Comment: about 31,000 revisions. Im much more of a git person myself but i think that translates into commits.

Comment: I'm interested in solving the problem for SubGit (as its developer). Do you have the logs after failing installation and idea why this revision is so special? If you're ready to collaborate, you can write to  
subgit-users@subgit.com

Comment: While i can't give out the entire log, as it contains information the company doesn't want to send out, i can send the error at the end. Subgit in particular has some strange behavior. It would get to about 80% and then start over. This went about 12 hours before it died completely.

Comment: If the SubGit guys can't sort it out and you can't get filter-branch to work report back.  It's a relatively straightforward process to stick together but not exactly trivial.

Comment: I finally got the config right on KDE's svn2git and it was able to convert the entire repo. So... problem solved! Still curious about how to accomplish my initial question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awesome guys at Github gave me an answer over email.

1. Fetch the earlier part of the git history into the Git repository containing the later part of the history:

`$ cd recenthistory 
$ git fetch ../oldhistory 'refs/*:refs/remotes/oldhistory/*'`

2. For each branch that appears both in the earlier and the later part of the history:

   - Find the oldest commit on the branch in the "recent" history. This should be an orphan commit (i.e., have no parents) so it should appear alone on the last line of the output from this command:

`$ git rev-list --topo-order --parents refs/heads/$BRANCH | tail 
[...] 
bf0c6e839c692142784caf07b523cd69442e57a5 e497ea2a9b6c378f01d092c210af20cbee762475 
e497ea2a9b6c378f01d092c210af20cbee762475 8bc9a0c769ac1df7820f2dbf8f7b7d64835e3c68 
8bc9a0c769ac1df7820f2dbf8f7b7d64835e3c68 e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290 
e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290`

- Create a graft to make it look like this commit actually has the tip of the corresponding branch in the old history as its parent:

`$ echo "e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290 $(git rev-parse "refs/remotes/oldhistory/$BRANCH")" >>.git/info/grafts`

3. After you have completed step 2 for all branches in your repository, use git filter-branch to make the grafts permanent:

`$ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags 
Verify that the history is correct.`

4. Push the resulting history to your GitHub repository. Please note that if you already have branches or tags in your GitHub repository, this will overwrite them!:

`$ git push origin --force --all 
$ git push origin --force --tags`

6. Clone a fresh copy from GitHub and double-check that everything is OK.
7. Delete the recenthistory and oldhistory repositories (perhaps making backups first). The histories in these repositories is not compatible with the history in GitHub, so you want to be sure not to do any further work in them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it following instructions in this link: http://blog.dynamic50.com/2009/11/26/moving-your-git-repos-and-all-branches-to-a-new-remote-repository/

To sum up, track locally the old branches, add the new remote and then push everything to it.

Comment: While this comes close, it just adds the repos together. I was hoping to link them as a continuous history as if the conversion script had never been interrupted.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead. Could you maybe update the answer to include more details?

Comment: That link no longer works

Answer (score 0):

How about this: (Pardon me if it sounds dumb)

Assumption: You have two repositories with all commits on one branch.

1. Fetch one repository into the other. (now you have two disconnected branches)
2. Rebase one branch over the other

Comment: Not all the commits are on one branch, though