# How to squash range of old git commits?

Tags: git, github

I have started a project as a fork of a CMS/framework that's intended to fork when you build on top of it. Lets say it has 500 commits and I don't want to keep that history for my project.

Ideally I want to squash the first 499 commits, keep the 500th as a pivot if I decide to cherry pick a range of patches after that. I have my commits on top of it but still pull patches occasionally.

My ~50 commits are already on top of the first 500 in my fork.

Would that be possible? How would I squash the first commits? I'd also consider other option, if there is better way to achieve what I hope for.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you *don't* nuke the history. Chances are *someone* will need it later, even if you can't imagine it yet.

Comment: @o11c The history stays in the original source.

Comment: also known as "not easily available when you need it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your fork as is, but also report your 50 commits on top of a new Git repo.

That new repo would be a clone of the original repo, in which you delete the `.git` (after cloning), and make a new git repo in it (`git init .; git add -A .; git commit -m "one big commit"`)

Then you can start importing the 50 commits from your first repo to this new one: see "[git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3816040/6309)".
I would use [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816292/6309).

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was hoping for!