# Moving module from one repo to another

Tags: git, github

I am relatively  new to git and I need to do the following.

1. Given a module, X ,in repo A, i want to move, X, to repo B
2. I need to do this why while preserving the history of certain authors. i.e  preserving the commit history of 'joe' and 'bob' and noting else.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks!.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816040/git-apply-changes-introduced-by-commit-in-one-repo-to-another-repo)

Comment: You don't define "module" here and that will likely be important. Meanwhile, note that in Git, the history *is* the commits. The two are inseparable. Each commit is a snapshot; history is formed by playing the snapshots over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Firstly add 'repo a' locally

```
git remote add repoa https://github.com/user/repoa.git
```

Then do a git push to that repo

```
git push repoa
```

Likewis eadd 'repo b' locally

```
git remote add repob https://github.com/user/repob.git
```

Then do a git push to that repo

```
git push repob
```

Doing this will push up the current state of the entire repository.

Now clone the repositories separately:

```
cd /path/where/you/want/new/repos/to/be
git clone https://github.com/user/repoa.git repoa
git clone https://github.com/user/repob.git repob
```

(where `repoa` as the 2nd param is the directory you want to clone into)

and for each run `git rm -r` with the directories/files you want to remove from that repo, for example for repo-a:

```
git rm -r src/repob docs/repob
```

Repeat the above again for repo-b.

Then for each repository run the following command to stage the deletions for commit:

```
git add -u
```

Then make a commit as you usually would:

```
git commit -m "Deleted files from repo b"
```

Then push

```
git push origin
```

Repeat the last 3 commands again for repo-b.

This will create two separate repositories with the complete history of all the files within the repo, unfortunately I don't know a way of retaining the history of 'only the files in that repo'.