# How to add a git submodule from other repo and merge it with local folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a specific situation and i didn't found the answer on stack that matches it.
I have a `root_project` which is base app directory, synchronized with it's remote repo.

Now i have a folder in it, which is named `oscar`. I've previously downloaded zipped [oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/src/oscar) and copied it into my `root_project`, after i've customised it in places i needed.
After that i have noticed that i get into troubles if i need to get updates from remote [oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/src/oscar) once those are made up.

The basic idea is to use `git submodule` but really can't figure out how to adapt it to my necesities as i don't want to crash my project and repo on experimenting.

Also a specific part is that i need only `src/oscar` from [oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/src/oscar) repo, that is actually in my `root_project` and to make it possible to merge with my changes in local `oscar` folder, without loosing the things i've already done locally.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions on how to use correctly `git submodule` in current circumstances, also if possible wanna see the steps i must do on achieving desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] as i don't want to crash my project and repo on experimenting.

First of all, you should not be afraid to try things in your local repository. As long as you stay on your local copy and do *not* publish experimental changes, you can always just delete the whole thing and clone it again from your remote. It is a very good way to learn stuff if you just try things out, especially when you break everything underway. Do not hesitate to do so!

To answer your question: I assume `oscar` exists as a remote repository. Git submodules are indeed a good way to manage a subrepository that you need to update occasionally. You can find good documentation on how to use submodules [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). It will be easier if you clone `oscar` directly from the remote via `git submodule add` instead of downloading and extracting a zip file first. This newly cloned submodule will of course not contain your local changes to `oscar`, but you can easily import them by following the steps [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816292/7598462).

> Also a specific part is that i need only src/oscar from oscar repo, that is actually in my root_project and to make it possible to merge with my changes in local oscar folder, without loosing the things i've already done locally.

I do not understand this part. Do you only want to add a subfolder of `oscar`as a submodule?

EDIT: So you want your submodule to conatin only a subfolder of the `oscar` repository. You can do this after cloning the whole repository (via `git submodule add`) with

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME
```

The process is described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/), although only point 5 is of interest for you. Note that you have to do this inside your submodule, i.e. you have to `cd` into your submodule folder.

Comment: Thx for suggestion, yes i want the ``src/oscar`` folder only, because the oscar repo includes also sandbox  and other stuff

Comment: As you can see here https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar the oscar git repo delivers the sandbox and other things i don't need to be synchronized with. I need src/oscar only to be merged with mine same folder in ``root_project``. Is it possible to do that the way you mentioned before ??

Comment: See my edit for details on how to extract a subfolder from the cloned submodule.

Comment: Thx for answering and paying attention on details, i guess this is what i need. I'll try this tomorrow and tell you if it worked :)