# How do I revert a specific commit that changed all files, causing lots of conflicts during revert?

Tags: git

In a collaborative repository, someone made a commit that somehow made it appear like it re-added all files in the repository again.

Here is part of the history when printed with `--date-order`:

```
* 28cbf861 - (65 minutes ago) update logs and metadata (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
* e589776e - (18 hours ago) P2LTR15 update
...
* d4c61147 - (5 days ago) Delete P2STR03_SRC00150_Q0448_0000_0-7.log
* fa837509 - (5 days ago) Delete P2STR03_SRC00150_Q0427_0000_0-7.log
*   9a5e2300 - (5 days ago) git pull at 20180421 10am.
|\
* | 6567df4b - (5 days ago) add md5 3min
* | 6f7c80f7 - (5 days ago) Added md5sum files for all 3min SRCs
 /
* b97e834f - (6 days ago) Delete P2STR13_SRC00605_Q0325_0000_0-9.log
* 5cd9989b - (6 days ago) Delete P2STR13_SRC00605_Q0129_0000_0-9.log
* 769ae25d - (6 days ago) Delete P2STR13_SRC00605_Q0209_0000_0-9.log
...
```

The faulty commit is `6f7c80f7`, and I would like to remove it, but keep `6567df4b`. The `git pull` commit (`9a5e2300`) is a simple merge commit.

When I print the history without `--date-order`, suddenly the commit `6f7c80f7` is shown at the very bottom, i.e. as if it was the first commit ever.

```
* 28cbf861 - (70 minutes ago) update logs and metadata
* e589776e - (18 hours ago) P2LTR15 update
...
* fa837509 - (5 days ago) Delete P2STR03_SRC00150_Q0427_0000_0-7.log
*   9a5e2300 - (5 days ago) git pull at 20180421 10am.
|\
| * b97e834f - (6 days ago) Delete P2STR13_SRC00605_Q0325_0000_0-9.log
...
| * 697a103c - (7 months ago) initial commit
* 6567df4b - (5 days ago) add md5 3min
* 6f7c80f7 - (5 days ago) Added md5sum files for all 3min SRCs
```

I tried doing a `git revert 6f7c80f7`, but it shows a lot of conflicts that I don't know how to resolve, that is, when I do a `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

You are currently reverting commit 6f7c80f7.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    P2LTR15/.gitkeep
    deleted:    P2LTR15/MOS_P2LTR15_MO.csv
    ... (this is basically a list of almost all the files in the repository)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by them: P2LTR15/P2LTR15.yaml
    deleted by them: P2LTR15/audioFrameInformation/P2LTR15_SRC00712_HRC021.afi
    ... (this is another list of files, I don't know why it is there, possibly those were actually changed)
```

Is there any other way I could rewrite the Git history in such a way that this bad commit never happened?

I've looked at [this guide](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed_new_simple) but it also only tells me to do a revert. Should I attempt to go back to a commit before that time, then [cherry-pick commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/435093) and then force-rewrite the repository? I don't think that will be a nice option either.

Comment: You can definitely try, but taking into account that it changed whole files, the problem is that new commits are going to be applied over those changed files. I don't think revert would work, so your best option would be [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816040/git-apply-changes-introduced-by-commit-in-one-repo-to-another-repo), that is, get the diffs produced after the "bad" commit and apply them using `git am`

Comment: So you're saying that it is impossible to revert that particular commit without creating another commit that again changes everything? Ideally I'd like to see a linear history again, and pretend that it never happened. Would the `git am` approach not be the same as cherry-picking the commits from the same repository?

Comment: It seems there are younger commits whose changes are dependent on `6f7c80f7`. `reset and cherry-pick` will also lead to conflicts. Since someone re-added all the files, there must be an older commit which had removed all the files. If the current revision is right, you could just leave it alone.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes, these are all dependent, although they aren't touching the same files as far as I can tell. The problem is that I have to manually verify that the current revision is “right”. Possibly I can run a diff on a detached repo at the state before the faulty commit to see what has *actually* been changed in terms of file content.

Comment: @slhck the diffs I have mentioned above will give you precisely that. They'll keep history, too, so they will be attributable to whoever did them.

Comment: @jjmerelo Hm, I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you please help me with a more specific instruction on how to follow that approach you suggested? Like, from where do I start applying these diffs? What happens with the bad commit? Why do I need these diffs in patch format etc. if they are in the history right now?

Comment: @slhck let me see if I can gather enough time to do that. But I'll answer your last question first: diffs are applied over text, while repo history takes into account the previous commits and so on. Once you delete a commit, all commits that have that one as a parent might have trouble. However, text need not have, since it's basically comparing lines. But you can also try reset and cherry-pick as ElpieKay says...

Comment: @jjmerelo I see, now that makes more sense. No worries, you've helped me a lot already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that your `git log` output quote is only *part of* the history, but you also say that commit `6f7c80f7` adds *all* the files, and in the quoted text, `6f7c80f7` never shows any parent commit to which it connects.

This suggests that `6f7c80f7` is a *root commit:* an initial commit that, in effect, adds every file that it shows, because the "previous" commit does not exist, so every file must by definition be new in that commit.

A graph *can* have more than one root.  It's a little bit unusual in a Git commit graph since we normally make new commits by first checking out some existing commit, then making changes, then running `git commit` to save a new complete snapshot.  But there are other ways:

- We can use `git fetch` to obtain an unrelated repository, then `git merge` with `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  If the Git version is old enough, `git merge` *always* allows unrelated histories, and does not have an `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag: it just merges these without warning.  (You might see a lot of `add/add conflict` errors here and have to do a lot of hand resolving though!)

  This adds *their*—the other repository's—root commit to our own commit graph, which already had our root commit, so now we have two root commits.
- We can use `git checkout --orphan` to set our own repository state up so that the next commit we make will be a root commit.

  (If and when we *do* make that root commit, we will have the same merge issues as with the "fetch unrelated repository" case.)
- We can, accidentally or deliberately, fiddle with Git internals, using plumbing commands like `git commit-tree` or just poking at files inside `.git`, to create a new root commit.

In any case, once we have this state where there are multiple roots and a merge commit that merges the extra root and then have built more commits atop the merge, we are sort of stuck with the situation.  The merge commit—in your case, `9a5e2300`—has a hash ID that *depends on* the existence of *both* chains of commits: the one leading back to the original root commit, and the one leading back to the new root commit.  The hash ID of any commit that has `9a5e2300` as a parent—in your case, this is just the one commit `fa837509`—depends on the existence of `9a5e2300`, as it literally incorporates that hash ID into its own ID.  The hash ID of the child of `fa837509` (again there is just one commit in your graph here) then depends on the existence of `fa837509`; if the rest of the graph is linear, each child in turn depends on *its* parent ID, all the way to the end.

Hence, if you were to somehow get rid of the extra root commit, your merge commit would need to have a different hash ID, which would mean every subsequent commit would *also* need to have a different hash ID.  Moreover, if you *did* rid yourself of `6f7c80f7`, the copy you would have to make of its current child `6567df4b` would *be* another root commit!  You would have to get rid of that one too, which would mean that there would be nothing for merge commit `9a5e2300` to merge, so you would probably want to ditch that as well—except that you'd want to somehow retain its *source snapshot*.  Then you would need to take all of the remaining (presumably linear) chain, from `fa837509` up to the tip, and copy each of *those* commits to new commits that do not depend on the existence of `9a5e2300`, but do use whatever commit you made that has the updated source snapshot from the merge commit.

Hence, this leads to the process you would have to use to avoid having two root commits:

- Copy the snapshot in merge `9a5e2300` to a new non-merge commit.  This gets a new hash ID (because it's a new unique commit).  Save that ID somewhere.
- Copy the snapshot in `fa837509` to a new commit, which likewise gets a new hash ID.  The new commit's parent would be the ID you just saved.  Save this ID somewhere.
- Copy the snapshot in the child of `fa837509` to a new commit, using the previous copy as the new parent.
- Repeat for every commit until you reach the tip.

Once you have this linear chain of commits that do not depend on the commits you want to get rid of, you can then simply *stop using* the original chain of commits that *does* depend on the commits you want to get rid of.  If you *and everyone else* do this, and you remove the names by which your Git *finds* the old chain, then it appears as if that old chain never existed.  With the *names* for them gone, eventually the old commits really do get removed.  (This happens when all the safety-checking timer stuff expires.  These safety checks exist so that you can get old commits back if you make a mistake but catch it soon enough—typically 30 days—and so that Git can make objects that are not yet connected up into the commit graph, but *will* be within 14 days.  Normal Git commands connect them up within a few milliseconds at worst, so 14 days is practically millennia.)

The above shows that it *is possible* to do what you are suggesting (though perhaps you would want to construct a slightly different replacement history than the one I described).  Whether it's a *good idea* is another question entirely.  The main drawback to rewriting history, however you do it—with `git rebase`, with `git filter-branch`, with [The BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), or with something you come up with on your own—is that the rewritten repository is, in effect, a *new* repository.  Or at least, the new chain is new: the old stuff, from before the rewrite point, is the same.  You must get *everyone who has copies of the old repository* to switch from the *old* stuff to the *new* stuff.  If even a *single person* retains the old commits, and uses Git to fuse the old with the new (which Git is quite happy to do), *all the old commits come right back*.  Now you have the old and the new all squished together into one big happy (?) repository and your problems have just gotten worse!

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with rewriting (some or all of) your commits into new history, you just need to (a) know how to do it and (b) be aware of this "everyone must switch" consequence.  If no one else has the commits that you're replacing, this kind of rewrite is completely safe—there's no *other person* or *other Git repository* that will bring the old commits back into play.  If everyone who *does* have the old commits understands how this works and plans to cooperate, this kind of history rewrite is *mostly* safe: it will go wrong only if someone makes a mistake (and then, depending on your own level of carefulness and/or paranoia, maybe only for them!).  It's when you have naive users, who just let Git's default [Borg-like action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)) of integrating every bit of technology it ever comes across, that this kind of rewrite makes a mess.

Comment: Wow, what a thorough answer, thanks! I guess that given the naïvety of some users involved (which led to this situation in the first place) I will perform a manual check between the files that existed before the faulty commit and the current state, and let the history stay as-is. In fact, the rest of the history is linear. (And I guess I will protect the master branch and force everyone to create merge requests instead of pushing to master.)

Comment: Github-style "protected" branches are handy for that sort of thing. They're annoying in other ways, but it's always a trade-off!