# how to push into someone else's repository after they clone mine?

Tags: git

I was able to successfully push my commits in my repository by my username and password. But I want to push those commits to someone who exactly forked my repository.I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) but It is on how to keep your repository sync with upstream repository. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can't do this unless you collaborate with the person that forked from your repo, well .. I think

Comment: What about if I am a contributor?

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Check out their repository
2. Create a branch
3. Replay the changes from your repository onto your branch in their repository
4. Push your changes
5. Create a pull request so they can merge your changes

Comment: Can you give me an example or a link on how to do those steps especially step number 3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816040/git-apply-changes-introduced-by-commit-in-one-repo-to-another-repo

Answer (score 1):

You could set his repository as a secondary remote upstream, like so:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

Give it any name you'd like, and the url of the forked repo (not the original one).

Then you can follow the same steps as the link you posted, replacing *upstream* with the upstream name you set up above.

Comment: In which step?


If on step 4, you can: a. create another branch from the fork's master branch, e.g. `git checkout fork_upstream/master -b fork/master`, or
b. reset the upstream from your local master to point to fork_upstream/master instead.


If you have checked out master from origin before, it will still be pointing to it. You would need a local branch pointing to the forked master.