# Git Already Up to Date Though I Made Changes

Tags: python, git, github, bitbucket, git-merge

I got two branches A, B.

In branch A, I added a file called a.py and consists:

```
import os
import math
```

I added and committed the file (and pushed to remote).

Than I created another branch, B like that:

```
git checkout -b B
```

in Branch B I added another file and added, committed and pushed it.

I also changed a.py to be like that:

```
import os
import sys
```

After that I also added 7 files and pushed them (in B).

Now, I regret and I want to keep the: `import math` by marging A to B without losing all my older commits. Only change back (but not manually) the import math back.

When I just use the IDE to merge A to B it says `already up to date` but it is not true because in A I have `import math` and in B I have `import sys`.

How can I fix it?

I'm afraid to lose all my job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are merging *how* exactly?

Comment: Using android-studio IDE

Answer (score 4):

Ipacheco is correct, but let me elaborate.

In git, when you merge two branches together, it doesn't consider what *content* is different. It considers what *commits* are different.

So you have branch A with `import math`. But more importantly you have commit #1.

When you branch from A to B, git copies commit #1 (with the `import math` change) to B. Then you make further changes -- commit #2. So B has a commit history of #1 and #2.

So when you try to merge A into B, git says that B already has commit #1 (you just overwrote it already). **Essentially, A does not have any new work that B doesn't have.** Thus B is "up to date".

If you want to go back, you actually have to revert the commits to B that have the changes you don't want.

EDIT: More specifically, you can use `git revert <commit>` from command line. This will add a new commit that undoes the specified commit. So you won't lose any work In between. But it does mean that both commits are in your history. (If that's a problem, look into `rebase` instead.) More on revert [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). Use `git log` to find the commit hash.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.
But if I revert the changes in B, my bew commits will be deleted :(
How can I both save the new commits and also have the `import math`?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

B is "already up to date" because it was a branch of A, and A wasn't updated after the B branch was created.

Comment: So what I need to do in order to be able to revert it to `import math` instead of `import sys`?

Comment: I'm not shure, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13565228/355364) might help.