# git practice exercise ( merging two branch and dealing with conflict)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have to clone this repo : https://github.com/glo2003/H21-tp1-git and integrate both branches which are :

**refactor/structure** and **fix/ingredients** to the **main** branch

Main currently looks like this :

```
Framboise
Banane
Champignon
```

**refactor/structure has a new folder called listes with the file liste.txt in it ( so the file structure is listes\listes.txt)** :

```
- Framboise
- Banane
- Champignon
```

**fix/ingredients** :

```
Framboise
Banane
Pommes
```

**The end result wanted is  this one (so champignon is replaced by Pommes and the list has a new format with the ' - ' also the folder structure will be listes\listes.txt**

```
- Framboise
- Banane
- Pommes
```

**What i tried :**

git clone https://github.com/glo2003/H21-tp1-git.git

git merge fix/ingredients

git merge refactor/structure

And i did git status to check to situation :

[image]

It looks like a listes.txt got deleted but not sure.

From there i wanted to fix the conflict, with vi listes.txt  or vi listes\listes.txt but i don't see any Head tag for the conflict so i am a bit confused ? What am i doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Correct, you get a conflict `liste.txt deleted in refactor/structure and modified in HEAD`. Now you must decide what you want Git to do. Did you want to accept the deletion or the modification?

Comment: In other words, yes, on main you have _liste.txt_ and it is Framboise, Banane, Pommes. But in the branch `refactor/structure` you have _listes/liste.txt_ and it is -Framboise, -Banane, -Champignon. What do you want to do about this?

Comment: @matt Well in refactor/structure everything is good, but the only change needed is to change Champignons to Pommes, but when i do  vi listes\listes.txt to change it, there's no Head tag where the conflict is so im not sure

Comment: This is not a textual conflict, it is a file level conflict. You cannot fix it by editing a file. You fix it by adding / removing from the index.

Comment: @matt well  Champignons needs to be changed to Pommes and the list as a ' - ' now ( see end result) So i guess it's textual in this case ? But yea theres a new folder since  liste is now in listes/liste.txt  how can i fix this ? Thanks :)

Comment: You can change manually whichever file you are planning on keeping, before doing the add or rm or both.

Comment: Ok, I see how to turn this into a text-level conflict you can resolve with `vi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a file level conflict, not a textual conflict. To fix it, you manipulate the index: you say `git add` to preserve a file and `git rm` to remove a file. Then say `git commit` to make it so.

For example, if you like what the restructure branch did, you can say

```
$ git rm liste.txt
$ git add listes/liste.txt
$ git commit -m"finish merge"
```

But then you have also accepted the contents of that file. If you wanted the contents to match `main`, you'd need to copy what's in the top level *liste.txt* into what's in *listes/liste.txt* before doing those file level things.

---

In the comments, you've basically said you *wish* this were a text-level conflict so you could resolve it at text level. To make that so, you need to:

1. Abort the merge.
2. Rearrange the file structure on `main` to match the file structure on the branch, and add and commit.
3. Now perform the merge, specifying it this way:

   ```
    git merge -Srecursive -Xno-renames refactor/structure
   ```

This will give you the moved *liste.txt* as a text conflict that you can proceed to resolve in `vi` or whatever.

So, here's how I solved it, from the start:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:glo2003/H21-tp1-git.git
$ cd H21-tp1-git/
# create local branches
$ git checkout fix/ingredients
$ git checkout refactor/structure
$ git checkout main
$ git merge fix/ingredients
$ git merge refactor/structure
# file-level conflict, abort
$ git merge --abort
# mimic "theirs" file structure, and merge
$ mkdir listes
$ git mv liste.txt listes/liste.txt
$ git add .
$ git merge -Srecursive -Xno-renames refactor/structure
# now we have the text level conflict you wanted, as we can see:
$ cat listes/liste.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
Framboise
Banane
Pommes
=======
- Framboise
- Banane
- Champignon
>>>>>>> refactor/structure
```

Comment: it confuses me a bit when you say it's not textual, i still need to change Champignon by Pommes ? i just go on and edit it ? with vi listes/liste.txt ? I really don't see how it's only a file problem when both files doesn't have the same text and the combination of both gives the good text. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's a complicated problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491270/git-merge-apply-changes-to-code-that-moved-to-a-different-file for some discussion.

Comment: OK I see how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `git merge`, git:

1. Finds some common / shared starting-point.  This is another commit, somewhere in history, from which both "you" (the person running `git merge`) and "they" (whoever produced the commit you're merging) started.
2. *Compares* the entire contents of the merge base to your current commit.  These are "your changes".  In your case, you changed an existing file, `liste.txt`.
3. *Compares* the entire contents of the merge base to their commit.  These are "their changes".  In their case, they *removed* an existing file, `liste.txt`, and *created* an *entirely different file*, `listes/listes.txt`.
4. Combines—or attempts to combine—these two sets of changes.

Conflicts occur when the changes cannot be combined automatically using the simple rules that Git has built in.  Here, the two changes that cannot be combined are:

- you modified some file;
- they removed that file entirely.

Git calls this a "modify/delete conflict".

Now, *you* claim that they *renamed* `liste.txt` to `listes/listes.txt`.  On what basis do you make this claim?  If the file contents of `listes/listes.txt` were *exactly the same* as the file contents of the former, now-deleted `liste.txt`, I might agree with you—and so might Git.  If your basis for this claim is that `liste.txt` and `listes.txt` are *sufficiently similar*, well, I don't see that off-hand.  Git doesn't see it either.  Once you point out that if we replace line 3 and make medium-small changes to lines 1 and 2, this degree of changing would alter the contents of `liste.txt` to match those in the new file `listes/listes.txt`, *then* I might agree—and so might Git.

In the end, what Git does with this, to decide whether some file was renamed, is to compute what Git calls a *similarity index*.  If the similarity index of the old file and the new file is high enough—meets or exceeds a 50%-similar threshold—Git will declare that the file was *renamed*, rather than deleting the left-side file (`liste.txt`) and creating an entirely new and different right-side file (`listes/listes.txt`).

You can control this rename similarity threshold, using `-X find-renames=number`.  You can also, as in [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946552/1256452), *disable* rename detection entirely, using `-X no-renames`.  That's useful if Git is *mis-classifying* something as a rename when it shouldn't—but if there are some renames that Git *should* find, you'll have to deal with them yourself.

In general, Git's similarity detection works pretty well on large files.  The reason it works so poorly on your sample file is that your sample file is tiny, and too many lines are too different.

Comment: The `no-renames` was the hard part for me. I initially just aborted the merge, rearranged the structure of `main`, and asked for the merge. But instead of the text conflict, I still got a file conflict, even though the structures matched! And you know why: in `main` this was a rename, but in the branch they had moved and edited in one move and it was _not_ seen as a rename but as a deletion. Ouch! It was the `no-renames` that prevented that.

Comment: I would have liked this to work the opposite way; I would have liked, in `main` to say `git mv --no-follow` or something similar, meaning, rename this file but please lose the history just as if I had done a move plus a heavy edit like in the other branch. But I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: @matt: in this case I'd also be concerned about getting an add/add conflict, if I fixed up the directory structure in a commit before merging. But that did actually work, with the `-X no-renames`, so that's worth noting. :-) As for `git mv`, all it does is update Git's index just as `git rm` and `git add` would: there's no flag to record moves. (Well, OK, it updates *and* also renames in the work-tree, which is convenient.)