# How to map back files which are moved mannually to git

Tags: git

I have a plenty of files which are moved from **folder A** to **folder B**. Not by git move command. And many changers are done for files in **folder A** in a *one branch* and many other changers to files in **folder B** in *another branch*. Now when I try to merge git does not know about this move. So it consider those folders as two different places and create two different files. Is there any way that I can show git that this file should map to that one ?

following are in timely order

- **folder A** : **Branch 1**
- create a new branch called **Branch 2** from **Branch 1**
- create a new folder called **folder B** and move all files in **folder A** to **folder B** (at **Branch 2**), and this is not a git move. Its a manual move of files
- keep development in both branches
- **Merge** : now git does not know the files in **folder A** and 1.) **folder A** : **Branch 1** are related. Merge really dont work as smooth.

Comment: The question is quite unclear with respect to folders and branches. It would be more helpful if you rephrase it with a concrete example: "I have had fileA in folderA that was moved to fileX still in folderA and that was recorded as a commit on branch *topic*, I also had fileB ..."

Comment: ok..i added more info

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897585/how-does-git-handle-merging-code-that-was-moved-to-a-different-file